# SQL Search query when models are not directly associated

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a match model.  A match is an association between a grant and a project.  On the match index I have a list of all the grant names and the the projects they are associated with.

I added a search bar to the match index and  I can search any field on the project table by doing this:

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      joins(:project)
      .merge(Project.where('project_name iLIKE ?', "%#{search}%"))
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

One of the fields on the project model is user_id.  What I would ultimately like to do is search in the match index by the name of the project's user.

I have two ideas of how to go about this:

### Idea One

Adjust the search method so I can join users to projects and then projects to matches so I can search by user name.

### Idea Two

I have defined user in my match model as shown below.

```
def user
 account.account_manager if account.present?
end
```

I also have a user column in the match index which is called by using "match.user.name".  However when I try to search by a user as seen below I get the warning "Association named 'user' was not found on Match".  Is there a way I can harness the user that I've already defined as a method?

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      joins(:user)
      .merge(User.where('name iLIKE ?', "%#{search}%"))
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Does it make sense to define an association where `match` has_many `users` through `projects`? If you could provide more details on the structure and cardinality of your relationships it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Match#user` is an ordinary method, ActiveRecord doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. So you should go with Idea One: join to your `users` table, and search against its column.